# FIrebase Google Auth Logout Error Connection refused

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I am trying to implment google auth into my firebase project. I am succesully able to login into the app but the problem happens at logout.

I receive the error
`GET http://localhost:4000/auth/logout net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

This seems to be an issue with my logout route which is defined in the code as this

```
export default function Dashboard() {
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const history = useHistory();

  async function handleLogout() {
    setError("");
    axios({
      method: "GET",
      withCredentials: true,
      url: "/auth/logout",
  
    })
      .then((res) => {
        Auth.deauthenticateUser();
        history.push("/login");

      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.response.data.message);
      });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {error && <p>{error}</p>}
      <h2>Home</h2>
      <p>Signed In</p>
      <button variant="link" onClick={handleLogout}>
        Log Out
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I think there is an issue with my logout route, any help would be appreciated.

Login Code

```
  function onGoogleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    provider.setCustomParameters({
      prompt: 'select_account'

    })
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then((result) => {
        setError("");
        console.log(result.user);
        Auth.authenticateUser();
        history.push("/");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setError(err.message);
      });
  }

  return (
    <div className="login-container">
      <div className="login-shadow-box">
       
      
   
          <button onClick={onGoogleSubmit}>Google</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Are you trying to signout from Firebase Auth? Also what is running on `http://localhost:4000` ? Is `/auth/logout` a route in your React App or on your server?

Comment: Yes i am trying to signout from firebase auth. The url is what is leading to the logout route from firebase

Comment: Why not use `signOut` method? Can you share code of `/auth/logout` page if that is a page?

Comment: That is the code for signing out its put into a logout route to make it easier to signout from multiple login options.

`router.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
  firebase
    .auth()
    .signOut()
    .then(() => {
      return res.status(200).json({ message: "Signout successful" });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return res.status(403).json({ message: error.message });
    });`

Comment: Is that an express app? You cannot use `signOut` method on your server. There is no user logged in on the server. That should be used on frontend itself. Please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
axios({
  method: "GET",
  withCredentials: true,
  url: "/auth/logout",
})
```

Axios will make a GET request at `https://domain.tld/auth/logout`. I'm not sure if that is server. But you can simply use `signOut` method to logout.

```js
async function handleLogout() {
  setError("");
  firebase.auth().signOut()
    .then((res) => {
      Auth.deauthenticateUser();
      history.push("/login");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err.response.data.message);
    });
}
```